# Should I only hunt in spring?

Tags: kittens-game

It seems like I'm consistently getting a lot more fur and ivory when I hunt in the spring compared to other seasons. Is this simply a confirmation bias or should I be pooling my catpower to hunt in the spring?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are seeing is pure confirmation bias.

The code for hunting is in village.js, there's a sendHuntersInternal function. The relevant bits list the following (omitting some irrelevant lines):

```
huntingRes.furs = this.rand(65) + this.rand(65 * hunterRatio);
```

```
if (this.rand(100) > ( 55 - 2 * hunterRatio)){
    huntingRes.ivory = this.rand(40) + this.rand(40 * hunterRatio);
}
```

```
if (this.rand(100) > 95){
    unicorns.value += 1;
}
```

Thus, there is always a random amount of furs, between 65 * (0 and 1 + hunterRatio) (hunterRatio is the number that Bolas and Hunting Armor and the like improve), there is a chance for ivory which is based on hunterRatio, with a result of a random number between 0 and 40 * (1 + hunterRatio), and there is always a 5% chance to find a single Unicorn. The season isn't used anywhere.